# Repetir elemento div para simular un slider infinito

Tags: php, html, css

Buenas,

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de realizar un `slider` que sea infinito. Actualmente tengo un `slider` con un `div` que tiene una animación de movimiento lineal que se repite.

```
<div class="cont-princ-slider">
    <img class="degradado" src="imagenes/fondo_blanco_slider.png" alt="">
    <div class="slier-prin">
        <div class="juegos_DWG">
            <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="juegos_DWG">
            <img src="caratulas/advaced_sp.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="juegos_DWG">
            <img src="caratulas/Active_Soccer_2_DX_XboxOne.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="juegos_DWG">
            <img src="caratulas/Alekhine's_Gun_XboxOne.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="juegos_DWG">
            <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="juegos_DWG">
            <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

La parte de CSS:

```
.cont-princ .cont-princ-slider { 
      width: 97%;
      height: 200px;
      background: black;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
}

.cont-princ-slider .degradado {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 5;
      left: -1px;
      height: 105%;
}

.slier-prin {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      animation: slider 16s infinite linear;
      outline: 2px solid blue;
}

.cont-princ-slider .juegos_DWG {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
}

@keyframes slider {
      to {
           left: -150%;
      }
}
```

Si utilizo un bucle `for` que me agregue hasta 3 veces la misma información obtengo más o menos los resultados que busco, pero no creo que eso sea bueno para la carga de la página:

```
<div class="slier-prin">

    <?php for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { ?>

          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/advaced_sp.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/Active_Soccer_2_DX_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/Alekhine's_Gun_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="juegos_DWG">
                <img src="caratulas/7_Days_to_Die_XboxOne.png" alt="">
          </div>


     <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Te refieres a un Slider tipo carrusel?

Comment: @StefanNolde Sí, eso es, pero que fuese infinito. De momento con la opción que he puesto al final de la pregunta lo "soluciono", aunque no está bien que haga eso porque cargo demasiado la página. Con imágenes sí que se podría hacer usando `background-image: repeat;` si no me equivoco.

Comment: Mi pregunta tuvo la meta de aclara eso, porque vi que tu pregunta esta recomendada para cierre por falta de claridad de que se pregunta. El hecho que yo adiviné correcto no soluciona eso para todos, así recomiendo que aclaras eso en tu pregunta. Un carrusel es implicitamente infinito, por ser redondo :)

Comment: He visto que usas php, que exactamente quieres hacer con el slider, animarlo automáticamente o dar al usuario la posibilidad de cambiarlo pro click? Eso determina que herramientas se te puede recomendar. Existe un ejemplo para lo que buscas (con anchors) en puro html/css3 [aquí en ingles](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-html-css-responsive-carousel-cari/). Podrías revisarlo.

Comment: @StefanNolde Sería un slider automático, el usuario no tendría que pulsar sobre ningún botón para hacerlo funcionar. El problema viene que cuando el contenido del div se acaba no aparece nada hasta que vuelve a empezar.

Answer (score 2):

Ya tienes hecho lo principal, como no hay interacción del usuario, una manera fácil de lograr lo que deseas es acudir a las animaciones `CSS3`, solo que en vez de utilizar `left` o `margin-left` (que si los sitúas en valores porcentuales son relativos al contenedor) deberías usar `translateX` (que en valores porcentuales es relativo al elemento en sí mismo). De esta manera si sitúas `translateX(-50%)` en un contenedor que tiene los elementos duplicados, este quedará exactamente en el mismo centro dejando visible la mitad derecha mientras la mitad izquierda quedaría oculta por el `overflow` `hidden`, este es el punto en que tu animación se debería terminar y volver a empezar y como los elementos son copia unos de otros no se notaría el salto.

En cuanto al duplicado de las imágenes lo deberías hacer por `JavaScript`. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional de lo que te comento:

```js
var slider = document.querySelector(".slier-prin");

slider.innerHTML += slider.innerHTML;
```

```css
.cont-princ-slider {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.slier-prin {
  display: inline-flex;
  -moz-animation: slider 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: slider 5s infinite linear;
  animation: slider 5s infinite linear;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.juegos_DWG {
  background: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

@keyframes slider {
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-princ-slider">
  <div class="slier-prin">
    <div class="juegos_DWG">01</div>
    <div class="juegos_DWG">02</div>
    <div class="juegos_DWG">03</div>
    <div class="juegos_DWG">04</div>
    <div class="juegos_DWG">05</div>
    <div class="juegos_DWG">06</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: me gusta mucho tu respuesta ^^ +1. He notado una cosa *rara*. si seleccionas el texto `"03"`  se mantiene seleccionado hasta que desaparece, luego cuando vuelve a aparecer por la derecha no lo está hasta la mitad que ya vuelve a estarlo ... xD una chorrada sin importancia

Comment: Hola @lois6b, es lógico lo que comentas, básicamente hay dos `03` (el original y el duplicado). Si seleccionas uno de los dos cuando llegue el otro no estará seleccionado y cuando la animación llegue a su fin y comience por el principio de nuevo, volverás a ver el `03` seleccionado. Una solución sería evitar que se seleccionaran los elementos para que no se note el truco ;)

Comment: OHhhh claro haha bueno, minucias. un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Claro que repetir la información con `php` para simular el efecto no es muy buena idea. Como tú ya lo anticipaste esto implica un exceso innecesario en los datos que viajan del servidor al cliente.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es duplicarlos ya en el cliente con `jQuery`. Tomas la información original y la duplicas lo necesario, luego la animas.

Funciona y te pueda dar pie a encontrar tu propia solución.

```
function duplicarProductos () {
    var $clones = $( '.contenedor .elementos' ).clone();
    //Si tus elementos tienen id y quieres modificarlo en los clones.
    //si duplicas más de una vez deberías tomarlo en cuenta para no tener id duplicados en el código final.
    $clones.each(function (index, element) {
        $( element ).attr( 'id', $( element ).attr( 'id' ) + '-clon' );
    });
    $( '.contenedor' ).append( $clones );
}
```